Linux + how to increase partitions based on disk size
we have some red-hat servers with the following details ( when OS disk size is 230G )
# lsblk
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0  230G  0 disk
├─sda1             8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2             8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3             8:3    0  228G  0 part
  ├─VG100-lv_root 253:0    0   20G  0 lvm  /
  ├─VG100-lv_swap 253:1    0   16G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─VG100-lv_var  253:2    0   30G  0 lvm  /var


fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 193.3 GB, 193273528320 bytes, 377487360 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   209715199   104857599+  ee  GPT

the Goal is to increase the /var and root filesystem based on that disk size is 230G
when current /var is 30G and root filesystem is 20G
so, we start with the following procedure that should gives us enough PFREE or enough  “Physical Free” space.
parted /dev/sda resizepart 3 100%
Error: The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk, as it should be.  This might mean that another operating system believes the disk is smaller.  Fix, by moving the backup to the end (and removing the old backup)?
parted: invalid token: 3
Fix/Ignore/Cancel?


sgdisk -e /dev/sda

note - sgdisk: The simplest way to fix the backup GPT table is by using the sgdisk command with the -e option, which moves the backup GPT data structures to the end of the disk
parted /dev/sda resizepart 3 100%
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.

partprobe /dev/sda

pvresize /dev/sda
  Failed to find physical volume "/dev/sda".
  0 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 0 physical volume(s) not resized

but from pvs Pfree is still 0
where we are wrong here ?
# pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda3  VG100 lvm2 a--  66.00g    0


Partition type is either MBR (msdos) or gpt for entire drive. You show drive as DOS, but then sda1 as gpt? And you have LVM or volumes. You resize volumes not partitions, if volume is entire drive which normally it is. https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/logical_volume_manager_administration/index  & https://askubuntu.com/questions/3596/what-is-lvm-and-what-is-it-used-for

One cannot format or resize a disk's partitions while any of the disk's partitions is mounted. When a partition is mounted, the disk's metadata (partition info, cluster allocation info, ...) is cached in the kernel. parted, gparted, or other formatting tools also manipulate the disk's metadata.  Chaos follows.
If you can, umount all the filesystems on the disk.
Boot from another medium, your install disk in "Try" mode or a Live distribution.
Ensure that none of partitions of the target disk is mounted, and that any swap partition is not used. Use df, sudo umount and swapoff. Read man df umount swapoff free.

so if I can't use the procedure, then what are the other alternative to increase the /var and root filesystem ?   ( on sda3 we have 228G )

One cannot format or resize a disk's partitions while any of the disk's partitions is mounted. That's not true. this is an extremely normal thing to do (at least when increasing the size of partitions mounted file systems, you can trigger a partscan afterwards; various file systems, including XFS, ext4 and other popular choices allow for online resizing. And: these aren't even partititions, they're logical volumes in LVM, whose foremost feature is online resizing.
